# Exiting from a loop on a runnable and move to next screen

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am almost a beginner on android. I am sort of stuck at a point. In the following code I am running a while loop for 30 times and runnable post delay is 3 seconds, means loop will run for 90 seconds(which is not important yet). It does so, thats fine. But in the runnable, when I call rangeofRouter0() function,the value in the textView changes to "You have reached the turn" when it goes into "else if" condition of rangeofRouter0() function and it must remove the callbacks as defined and move to next activity, exitiing from the while loop whether it has completed 90 seconds or not but program doesn't reach in if(textView.getText.equals....) part. And if I put this condition directly into "else if", callbacks are (I think) not removed and next screen is called again and again. I want that when code goes into else if, it should simply move to next screen and previous activity(means this activity), should simply be forgotten

```
    int i = 1;

    while (i<30)

    {
        myRunnable =new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                scanWifiList();
                rangeofRouter0();

            }

        };

        handler1.postDelayed(myRunnable, i * 3000);

        i++;

        if(textView.getText().toString.equals("You have reached the turn")){
            ///this text gets in textView in "else if" condition

            handler1.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FrontScreen.class);
            // finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }//While loop ended


  private void scanWifiList() {
    mainWifi.startScan();
    wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
    textView5.setText("" + firstRouterDistance());

}


    public void rangeofRouter0(){     
    if(firstRouterDistance() >= 30 &&
            firstRouterDistance() <= 70 && ((degree>0 && degree <60)||(degree>300 && degree <360)))
    {
        textView.setText("Move left");
        speakOut(textView.getText().toString());
    }


    else if(firstRouterDistance() >= 3 &&
            firstRouterDistance() <= 20 &&
            secondRouterDistance() >= 7 &&
            secondRouterDistance() <= 60 && degree>220 && degree <250)
    {
        textView.setText("You have reached the turn");
        counter++;
    }
    else{
        textView.setText("Not before dining hall");
    }

}
```

Comment: Re, "when I call `rangeofRouter0()` function, it increments the counter by one":  I can see that your rangeofRouter0() function conditionally implements a variable named `counter`, and I can see that the code fragment at the top of your example tests a variable named `counter`, but `counter` is a free variable in both places.  How do I know that both bits of code refer to the same variable?  I think you need to post a more complete example.

Comment: `postDelayed` is an asynchronous call, so your loop will not run for 90 seconds. It is most likely only a few ms.

Comment: @jameslarge counetr is a public int variable declared before onCreate

Comment: @dharms thats alright but I want just want to remove callback for the runnable and move to next activity smoothly by making my code reach into if(counter>0) condition and  without this activity being called again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to understand how `postDelayed()` works exactly.

When you assign a runnable to the `Handler's postDelayed()`, that means you are scheduling a task to get executed at a particular time interval from the current time.
Now what you are doing is running a while loop 29 times and each time scheduling the task - total 29 tasks to run at 3,6,9... seconds respectively.
At this point you only scheduled the task and it's not started running yet.
And you while loop finishes after iterating for 29 times.
Your `rangeofRouter0()` never gets called during the while loop iterations since it took only a few milliseconds and hence `counter` is never greater than 0.

**Note** - If you want the loop to run for 30 times you should change it to `while (i<=30)`.

So, you need to change your logic to achieve what you want. If you want to read more about `Handler`. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)).

Comment: shadab I have edited the quesstion and removed counter variable's condition. Kindly go through it again if you can help

Comment: It will still behave the same. You need to change your logic. My suggestion - move the code for launching activity and removing callbacks to  the `rangeofRouter0()` just after `textView.setText("You have reached the turn");`

Comment: then the the next screen is called again again because loop has not yet completed

Comment: You should not use loop. Try scheduling task in your `rangeofRouter0()` if some condition fails.